# How do I get values from a text file and put them into a dataframe in python?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a text file and want to get its values and want to put them in a dataframe in python. I know I have to use read_csv but not sure how to do it.

The text file looks something like this:

duration,protocol_type,service,flag,src_bytes,dst_bytes,land,wrong_fragment,urgent,hot,num_failed_logins,logged_in,num_compromised,root_shell,su_attempted,num_root,num_file_creations,num_shells,num_access_files,num_outbound_cmds,is_host_login,is_guest_login,count,srv_count,serror_rate,srv_serror_rate,rerror_rate,srv_rerror_rate,same_srv_rate,diff_srv_rate,srv_diff_host_rate,dst_host_count,dst_host_srv_count,dst_host_same_srv_rate,dst_host_diff_srv_rate,dst_host_same_src_port_rate,dst_host_srv_diff_host_rate,dst_host_serror_rate,dst_host_srv_serror_rate,dst_host_rerror_rate,dst_host_srv_rerror_rate
0,icmp,ecr_i,SF,1032,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,511,511,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,255,255,1.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0

Where all the strings are what I want to use for rows and the rest of them are values. I am using pandas in anaconda and the text file is called kddcup.txt. If anyone can help me out it would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried using `read_csv` and giving it the path for your file?

Comment: No, how would I do that? @JonClements

Comment: Do you know how to import pandas and how to call functions?

Comment: @rajzaveri5 did you try ` df = pd.read_csv('name_of_the_text_file.csv')` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. Path to file is wherever your file is located, the relative path.

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('path_to_file.csv', sep=',')
```